# Display XML schema data in treeview in a textbox

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xsd

I am new to this project. It is on visual studio 2010 in C#. I am trying to show this XML schema in a textbox with a treeview. I have problem making it into a treeview.

> ```
>             DataSet dsM= new DataSet("M");
>             string filePath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\M.xsd";
>             dsM.ReadXml(filePath);
>             System.IO.StringWriter swXML = new System.IO.StringWriter();
>             dsM.WriteXmlSchema(swXML);
>             textBox.Text = swXML.ToString();
> ```

Comment: `XML schema in a textbox with a treeview` really? please clarify a bit. Are you trying to display the XML schema of a trieview's datasource / data in a textbox? Or is it that you want to get the XML string and present it as a Treeview?

Answer (score 5):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

public class XmlTreeDisplay : System.Windows.Forms.Form{
    private System.Windows.Forms.TreeView treeXml = new TreeView();

    public XmlTreeDisplay() {
        treeXml.Nodes.Clear();
        this.Controls.Add(treeXml);
        // Load the XML Document
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string filePath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\M.xsd";

        try {
            doc.Load(filePath);
        }catch (Exception err) {

            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            return;
        }

        ConvertXmlNodeToTreeNode(doc, treeXml.Nodes);
        treeXml.Nodes[0].ExpandAll();
    }

    private void ConvertXmlNodeToTreeNode(XmlNode xmlNode, 
      TreeNodeCollection treeNodes) {

        TreeNode newTreeNode = treeNodes.Add(xmlNode.Name);

        switch (xmlNode.NodeType) {
            case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                newTreeNode.Text = "<?" + xmlNode.Name + " " + 
                  xmlNode.Value + "?>";
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                newTreeNode.Text = "<" + xmlNode.Name + ">";
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Attribute:
                newTreeNode.Text = "ATTRIBUTE: " + xmlNode.Name;
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
            case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                newTreeNode.Text = xmlNode.Value;
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                newTreeNode.Text = "<!--" + xmlNode.Value + "-->";
                break;
        }

        if (xmlNode.Attributes != null) {
            foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in xmlNode.Attributes) {
                ConvertXmlNodeToTreeNode(attribute, newTreeNode.Nodes);
            }
        }
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in xmlNode.ChildNodes) {
            ConvertXmlNodeToTreeNode(childNode, newTreeNode.Nodes);
        }
    }
    public static void Main(){
       Application.Run(new XmlTreeDisplay());
    }
}
```

modify this to suit your needs...

(to do the reverse, convert a TreeView to XML, [here is a nice demonstration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/treeviewtoxml.aspx) not necessary repeating here)

Comment: Thanks it can work perfectly but I have my own UI and it has a button so after I click on it, how can I make the xml with treeview  to show on the textbox??

Comment: @mcnemesis is there someway to convert it back?

Comment: as in from Treeview into XML?

Comment: check the updated solution, ps, accept an answer if it was it :-)